# setting a radGrid to edit mode from an external button

Tags: asp.net, radgrid

I have a rad grid where I can insert/update and delete items of data.

i have set up a CommandItemTemplate with a button that, when clicked will put the grid in edit mode.

What I would like to do is have the same functionality but from an external asp.net button. If I can get this button to trigger the radGrid_ItemCommand event then I could get it working. But how do I pass the relevant GridCommandEventArgs from a asp.net button ?

Any help is always appreciated

Truegilly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wouldn't fire ItemCommand, but I think you change the edit status by adding the row index to edit via EditIndexes collection ([Telerik RadGrid - How do I default to edit mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674307/telerik-radgrid-how-do-i-default-to-edit-mode)).  This wouldn't invoke the command event I don't believe, but the editing event.

HTH.

Answer (score 3):

```
protected void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rgGrid.MasterTableView.InsertItem();
}
```