# user can not change checkbox in radgrid

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, radgrid

I use this code to add a checkbox column to radgrid.In my program,i want to add row dynamically.but when i use my code and run program,checkbox is disabled for user and he/she can not changed it.what should i do to allow user that cand change checkbox?

my code:

```
<telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn DataField="Discontinued" HeaderText="Discontinued"
                                      DataType="System.Boolean" ShowFilterIcon="False">
                                </telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn>
```

and dynamically add rows:

```
 DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("DeliveryID");
            table.Columns.Add("DeliveryName");

            DataRow dr = table.NewRow();

            dr["DeliveryName"] = "uk";

            table.Rows.Add(dr);

            DataRow dr2 = table.NewRow();

            dr2["DeliveryName"] = "US";

            table.Rows.Add(dr2);



            RadGrid1.DataSource = table;

            RadGrid1.Rebind();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GridCheckBoxColumn` can only be checked/unchecked when the grid is in edit mode. There is already a great deal of information out there to answer your question. Try these to start:

- [How do I set Telerik RadGrid to Edit mode by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379448/how-do-i-set-telerik-radgrid-to-edit-mode-by-default-asp-net)
- [GridCheckboxColumn checkboxes don't work](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/gridcheckboxcolumn-checkboxes-don-t-work.aspx)